# The receipt date does not match to the sandbox duration

Tags: ios, swift, subscription, auto-renewable

My app has auto renewable subscription. I tried to test the correct workflow of the subscription. According to WWDC 2018:
[image]

I created a new subscription with one week duration. I created a new sandbox user, and tried to activate my new subscription. Here is the code:

```
guard let httpResponce = responce as? HTTPURLResponse,
    let contentType = httpResponce.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String,
    let expirationDate = self.parcedReceipt?.inAppPurchaseReceipt?.subscriptionExpirationDate,
    let serverDate = self.parseDateAndTime(getResDate: contentType) else {
        result(false, ReceiptError.unexpectedError.localizedDescription)
        return
}
self.saveDateAndTime(dateForSave: serverDate)
self.ls.pmsg("serverTime:\(serverDate), receiptDate:\(expirationDate)")
```

I verify date and time with server. The result is the same - I always get receiptDate like: current time + one hour:

```
XXX.swift validateTimeWithServer(result:) serverTime:2018-07-11 13:18:16 +0000, receiptDate:2018-07-11 14:18:16 +0000
```

But my subscription is only one week.

[image]

Why is this happened? Is it possible that date of the receipt is one hour but in reality the AppStore renew it after 3 min?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of introductory price. If the subscription has an introductory price the subscription period will be wrong. In my case I deleted an introductory price and the duration for a sandbox user started to be 3 min.